How to customize the direction of input's text that inside v-select
To customize the direction of the input placeholder in the v-select component based on the chosen language in a multilingual website.
<v-select
    v-model="add.city"
    :options="cities"
    :label="$store.getters['GET_LANG_NAME'] === 'ar' ? 'nameAr' : 'nameEn'"
    :placeholder="$t('addresses.city')"
    required
    class="select"
    :input-props="{ dir: $store.getters['GET_LANG_NAME'] === 'ar' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr', style: { textAlign: $store.getters['GET_LANG_NAME'] === 'ar' ? 'right' : 'left' }}"
>
</v-select>

i try to use a conditional approach to dynamically set the direction and alignment of the placeholder text. but it doesn't work

just to be clear, you want to display the placeholder text vertically or horizontally?

i need to display horizontally

have you checked if setting the direction attribute on v-select solves the problem? it cna either be horizontal or vertical

Ok thanks i solved by putting classe based on condtion the language of website and if it ar do text-align :right
